# What Should the Formula for this Map Be?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

We have $\phi:$${R/H\to G}$, where $(R,+)$ is a group, $H = ${$2n$$\pi$$:n$$\epsilon$$Z$} is a subgroup and $G$ is a group of matrices given as $\begin{bmatrix}cos{\theta}&-sin{\theta}\\sin{\theta}&cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix},$ where ${\theta}$$\epsilon$$R$ and the group operation is matrix multiplication.

I want to give an explicit formula for the map $\phi.$ So, I started by saying let $y$$\epsilon$$R/H.$ Then, $y=x+H$ for $x$ $\epsilon R$. This means $\phi(x+H)$ $=$ $\phi(x)$$=g,$ for $g$$\epsilon$$G.$ I don't know how to express the matrix part. That is, I don't know what $g$ should be. I am thinking of taking it as a matrix whose determinant is always 1 but I still don't know what to do with that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a map $\phi:R\to G$ with the property $\phi(x+H)=\phi(x)$, then this leads to a map $\phi:R/H\to G$ (where calling both maps $\phi$ seems like an abuse of notation). You just need $\phi(x)$ to be $2\pi$-periodic in $x$. You can write $\phi(x)$ as
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x)=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos f(x) & -\sin f(x) \\ \sin f(x) & \cos f(x)\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $f(x)$ is any function such that $\cos f(x)$ and $\sin f(x)$ are both $2\pi$-periodic. The necessary and sufficient conditions for the composition of two functions to be periodic do not seem to be known. For any natural number $N$, any $(2\pi/N)$-periodic function $f(x)$ will do, but there are others.

To give three examples, the function $f(x)=x$ leads to possibly the most interesting map, which is an [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) (i.e., it preserves the group structure, meaning $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$):
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x)=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation*}
the function $f(x)=0$ leads to the less interesting map
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation*}
and the function $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ also leads to a valid map:
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x)=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos \left[\sin(2x)\right] & -\sin \left[\sin(2x)\right] \\ \sin \left[\sin(2x)\right] & \cos \left[\sin(2x)\right]\end{matrix}\right).
\end{equation*}

Comment: Okay, I get it. Just need one more clarification: do we say $\phi(x+H)$ = $\phi(x)$ as a convention?

Comment: it seems $\phi$ will not be well defined since it is a periodic function. Take for instance, we know that $0$ $\neq$ 2$\pi$ but $\phi(0)$ = $\phi$(2$\pi$) if we take $\phi(x)$ = $\begin{bmatrix}sinx&-cosx\\cosx&sinx\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @MrProf well, in $R/H$, the element $0$ is the same as the element $2/pi$. The function $\phi$ is periodic in $R$ but not in $R/H$, because by definition, $R/H$ cannot contain two elements that differ by a multiple of $2\pi$. In any case, why would a periodic function not be well defined?

Comment: You raised the issue that staggered me: 'why would a periodic function not be well defined?'. We know trig functions, like other periodic functions, are well defined. I used to think if I could establish that if $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$, I can conclude that $f$ is well-defined. However, $b$ could be $a+something$ in a periodic function!. To be more specific, how should I go about showing that the map $\phi$ in this question is well defined if we take $\phi(x)$ = $\begin{bmatrix}cosx&-sinx\\sinx&cosx\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What do you mean by "well defined"?. A "well defined map (function)" is just a correspondence between two sets where each element of the first set corresponds to exactly one element of the second set (but it is possible for two elements of the first set to correspond to the same element of the second set). In other words: if for every $x$ there is one $\phi(x)$, then the map is well defined.

Comment: Injective is a stronger condition. None of the maps $\phi:R\to G$ that satisfy the condition $\phi(x)=\phi(x+H)$ are injective.

Comment: Let's say we show f is injective. Will that do the job? It seems it is like using a stone to kill two birds except that it does not take care of the fact that we could have two distinct objects with the same image

Comment: okay, now I get it. Thanks